# screenshot whole view with scrollview on activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to take screen shot for whole layout including scroll view on activity.like if my screen of 800dp while my screen height is 400dp so i want to cover full 800dp.how can i do it?i see many tutorial it only teach how to screen shot in showing details only not hidden details?how can i do it?. for to create invoice page for particular product in android.is it possible?any one please help me...

[image]

Comment: There are apps that stick two screenshots together, if that is what you are looking for

Comment: i want to create invoice sheet for buyer product conformation.so i need to take screen shot for entire activity into images then convert pdf for buyer needs...

Answer (score 0):

Take screenshot of your layout with below code

```
        View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
            //Create a Bitmap with the same dimensions 
            Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), 
                                               view.getHeight(), 
                                               Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            //Draw the view inside the Bitmap

            Canvas canvas=new Canvas(image);
            view.draw(canvas);
```